# Is $n^2$ bigger than $n\log n $?

Tags: algorithms

How to prove $n^2$ is bigger than $ n\log n $?

Do I have to use *L'Hôpital's Rule*?

Can you give me an idea?

Comment: May be you can try comparing $n$ with $\log n$ and forget the multiple in both...

Comment: If by bigger you mean $\n log n \in O(n^2)$, then yes. Since

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true if and only if $n > \log(n)$, which you can prove by exponentiating and using Taylor series.